# Changing the color of the cell on the left

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Can anyone help with this google sheet formula. If any cell contains text "Done", I would like that cell and the cell on it's left to turn green. It is not bound to a specific column.

[image: turn green too]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use on range **`B:P`**:

```
=(C1="done")+(B1="done")
```

[image]

Comment: This is Much better. Kudos :)

Comment: This works perfect! Thank you! How does the formula work for all columns when you've only used C1 and B1?

Comment: @Charlie by default, conditional formatting runs for each cell in range B:P. this is because we did not lock it with `$`. to run it only on B and C column formula would be: `=($C1="done")+($B1="done")`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation @player0 ! Would you mind breaking down the formula =(C1="done")+(B1="done"). I am a total newbie.
1. What does + do?
2. How does it know to color the cell on the left when a cell has "done"?
3. How does B & C work for all columns in B:P?

Comment: @Charlie plus + sign stands for OR logic gate https://i.stack.imgur.com/KQTd0.png while AND would be symbolized as * multiplication. so in other words if either or both of those cells are equal to "done" both cells will lit up

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the `$` sign

```
=$C2="Done"
```

[image]

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This formula would only range for column B and C, and I would have to duplicate this for other columns. I'm looking for a formula that would apply to any column in the sheet.